# ctx parameter in multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I´m trying to use a Queue from the multiprocessing.Queue module.
The Implementation (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) uses

```
q = Queue()
```

as an example for instantiation. If i try this, i get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'ctx'
```

Googling the problem brought up this:

http://bugs.python.org/issue21367

How do i know if this is fixed? Is it impossible to use multiprocessing.Queues right now?
If not, how do i get the needed ctx object (and what is it?)

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: How are you importing `Queue`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It sounds like you're not importing `Queue` directly from `multiprocessing`. When contexts were introduced, most of the objects you import from the `multiprocessing` top-level package became functions which internally get a context, then pass that to an underlying class initializer, rather than being classes themselves. For example, here is what `multiprocessing.Queue` is now:

```
def Queue(self, maxsize=0):
    '''Returns a queue object'''
    from .queues import Queue
    return Queue(maxsize, ctx=self.get_context())
```

If you were to import `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` directly and try to instantiate it, you'll get the error you're seeing. But it should work fine if you import it from `multiprocessing` directly.

The context object tells `multiprocessing` which of the [available methods for starting sub-processes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) is in use. `multiprocessing.Queue` uses a `multiprocessing.Lock` internally, which has to know the correct context to function properly.

Answer (score 7):

This is how should multiprocessing Queue class be inherited from Python 3.4 and on:

```
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue

class BlockedQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=-1, block=True, timeout=None):
        self.block = block
        self.timeout = timeout
        super().__init__(maxsize, ctx=multiprocessing.get_context())
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: "from multiprocessing import Queue"?