# Cannot subclass multiprocessing Queue in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

My eventual goal is to redirect the `stdout` from several subprocesses to some queues, and print those out somewhere (maybe in a little GUI).

The first step is to subclass `Queue` into an object that behaves much like the `stdout`. But that is where I got stuck. Subclassing the multiprocessing `Queue` seems impossible in Python v3.5.

```
# This is a Queue that behaves like stdout
# Unfortunately, doesn't work in Python 3.5   :-(
class StdoutQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        Queue.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs, ctx='')

    def write(self,msg):
        self.put(msg)

    def flush(self):
        sys.__stdout__.flush()
```

I found this snippet in the following post (probably Python 3.5 did not yet exist at that moment): [Python multiprocessing redirect stdout of a child process to a Tkinter Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947281/python-multiprocessing-redirect-stdout-of-a-child-process-to-a-tkinter-text)

In Python v3.5 you stumble on strange error messages when subclassing the multiprocessing `Queue` class. I found two bug reports describing the issue:

https://bugs.python.org/issue21367

https://bugs.python.org/issue19895

I have 2 questions:

1. Suppose I want to stick to Python v3.5 - going to a previous version is not really an option. What workaround can I use to subclass the multiprocessing Queue somehow?
2. Is the bug still around if I upgrade to Python v3.6?

---

**EDIT :**

There is a known issue when you try to subclass the `Queue` class found in here:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue    # <- known issue: you cannot subclass
                                     #    this Queue class, because it is
                                     #    not a genuine python class.
```

But the following should work:

```
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue   # <- from this Queue class, you
                                           #    should be able to make a
                                           #    subclass. But Python 3.5
                                           #    refuses :-(
```

Sadly, even that doesn't work in Python v3.5. You get the following error:

```
    C:\Users\..\myFolder > python myTest.py

        Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "myTest.py", line 49, in <module>
              q = StdoutQueue()
            File "myTest.py", line 22, in __init__
              super(StdoutQueue,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'ctx'
```

---

**EDIT :**

Thank you Darth Kotik for solving the problem! Here is the complete code, updated with his solution. Now it works.

```
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.queues as mpq
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *

'''-------------------------------------------------------------------'''
'''                SUBCLASSING THE MULTIPROCESSING QUEUE              '''
'''                                                                   '''
'''         ..and make it behave as a general stdout io               '''
'''-------------------------------------------------------------------'''
# The StdoutQueue is a Queue that behaves like stdout.
# We will subclass the Queue class from the multiprocessing package
# and give it the typical stdout functions.
#
# (1) First issue
# Subclassing multiprocessing.Queue or multiprocessing.SimpleQueue
# will not work, because these classes are not genuine
# python classes.
# Therefore, you need to subclass multiprocessing.queues.Queue or
# multiprocessing.queues.SimpleQueue . This issue is known, and is not
# the reason for asking this question. But I mention it here, for
# completeness.
#
# (2) Second issue
# There is another problem that arises only in Python V5 (and beyond).
# When subclassing multiprocessing.queues.Queue, you have to provide
# a 'multiprocessing context'. Not doing that, leads to an obscure error
# message, which is in fact the main topic of this question. Darth Kotik
# solved it.
# His solution is visible in this code:
class StdoutQueue(mpq.Queue):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        ctx = mp.get_context()
        super(StdoutQueue, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs, ctx=ctx)

    def write(self,msg):
        self.put(msg)

    def flush(self):
        sys.__stdout__.flush()


'''-------------------------------------------------------------------'''
'''                           TEST SETUP                              '''
'''-------------------------------------------------------------------'''

# This function takes the text widget and a queue as inputs.
# It functions by waiting on new data entering the queue, when it
# finds new data it will insert it into the text widget.
def text_catcher(text_widget,queue):
    while True:
        text_widget.insert(END, queue.get())

def test_child(q):
    # This line only redirects stdout inside the current process
    sys.stdout = q
    # or sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__ if you want to print the child to the terminal
    print('child running')

def test_parent(q):
    # Again this only redirects inside the current (main) process
    # commenting this like out will cause only the child to write to the widget
    sys.stdout = q
    print('parent running')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mp.Process(target=test_child,args=(q,)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui_root = Tk()
    gui_txt = Text(gui_root)
    gui_txt.pack()
    q = StdoutQueue()
    gui_btn = Button(gui_root, text='Test', command=lambda:test_parent(q),)
    gui_btn.pack()

    # Instantiate and start the text monitor
    monitor = Thread(target=text_catcher,args=(gui_txt,q))
    monitor.daemon = True
    monitor.start()

    gui_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Looks like the same issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941359/ctx-parameter-in-multiprocessing-queue

Comment: Hi @BiRico , thank you very much. Unfortunately, it is not the same issue. The issue described in that post is about instantiating a Queue-object. The issue of subclassing Queue is not mentioned, nor explained.

Comment: I was able to make a subclass in Python 3.5.2 but cannot get the queue to terminate yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> type(multiprocessing.Queue)
<class 'method'>
AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing' has no attribute 'queues'
>>> import multiprocessing.queues
>>> type(multiprocessing.queues.Queue)
<class 'type'>
```

So as you can see `multiprocessing.Queue` is just constructor method for `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` class. If you want to make a child class just do `class MyQueue(multiprocessing.queues.Queue)`

You can see source of this method [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L99-L102)

**EDIT**:
Okay. I got your problem now. As you can see  on a link above, `multiprocessing.Queue` passes `ctx` argument to Queue. So I managed to get it working by doing it myself in `__init__` method. I don't completely understand where `BaseContext` object supposed to get `_name` attribute, so I passed it manually.

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    from multiprocessing.context import BaseContext
    ctx = BaseContext()
    ctx._name = "Name"
    super(StdoutQueue,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs, ctx=ctx)
```

**EDIT2**: Turned out docs have some information about context [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods). So instead of manually creating it like I did you can do

```
import multiprocessing
ctx = multiprocessing.get_context()
```

It will create proper context with `_name` set (to 'fork' in your particular case) and you can pass it to your queue.

Comment: I have tried both ways (multiprocessing.Queue and multiprocessing.queue.Queue), but none works.

Comment: Hi @Darth Kotik , I have added an edit to my question. There I show the complete example, and the detailed error message. Do you work on Python 3.5? It would be great if you could reproduce the error :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it out and let you know if it works :-)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for helping me out on this. I have updated my question: your solution is now visible in the code :-)

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with you project!